# Show number of rows from a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to show number of rows from a grid view using a label. I used SQL Count statement but it doesn't work. The problem is I only get only number 1 shown in the label which is not matched with the number of rows I have in my table! I have posted similar question but unfortunately no body gave a clear answer!

My codes as:

Basket.ac

```
  public int td()
   {
       int customers;
        //I tried this select query but still gets number 1
       //String sql = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Baskets");
       string sql = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Baskets");
       customers = Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows.Count;

       //customers = Convert.ToInt32(Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows.Count);
       return customers;


    }
```

DataBaseConn.ac

```
 public class DataBaseConn
  {
   SqlConnection conn;
   SqlCommand cmd;
   DataTable tbl;
   private void Intialise(CommandType commandtype, string DataBase)
   {

    conn = new SqlConnection();
    cmd = new SqlCommand();

    //Requirements
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ToString();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = commandtype;
    cmd.CommandText = DataBase;
    conn.Open();
  }

 public int RunProcedure(string Procedure, SortedList ParameterV)
  {

    Intialise(CommandType.StoredProcedure, Procedure);


    for (int i = 0; i < ParameterV.Count; i++)


        try
        {
            if (ParameterV.GetByIndex(i) != null)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParameterV.GetKey(i).ToString(), 
                                                 PrameterV.GetByIndex(i).ToString());
        }
        catch { ;}

    return RunUpdate();

   }

  public int RunUpdate(string InsDelUpd)
   {

    Intialise(CommandType.Text, InsDelUpd);
    return RunUpdate();

  }

   private int RunUpdate()
   {
    try
   {      
        int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return x;
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
      {
        conn.Close();
        return ex.Number;
      }

   }

  public DataTable RunQuery(string Select)
   {
    Intialise(CommandType.Text, Select);
    tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();
    return tbl;

   }
 public bool EData(string selection)
  {

    if (RunQuery(selection).Rows.Count > 0)
        return true;
    else
         return false;

    }


 }
```

Basket.aspx

```
    lblQueue.Text = _b.td().ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to return the data table's `.Rows.Count` - this will always be 1 (as in `1 row(s) affected`) for your `count(*)` query.

You should instead look at using [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) to return the first column of the first row from your query

I'm not sure how you want to build this into your `DataBaseConn` data helper class, but the gist of it is you need the following sequence:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringHere))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn))
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Baskets";
   return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

**Edit**

If you aren't able to extend your `DataBaseConn` helper with an `ExecuteScalar`, then I guess you'll be able to use the existing `RunQuery` method which returns a DataTable. Just scrape the first column of the first row like so:

```
return Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows[0].Field<int>(0);
```

As a side note, you might look at replacing your `DataHelper` entirely with the Microsoft Patterns and Practices [Data Application Access Block (DAAB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726(v=pandp.60).aspx), or, if you prefer, look at using an ORM like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). By upgrading to a mainstream Data Access encapsulation, you won't need to spend as much time debugging data access issues like this one :)

Comment: You use the ExecuteScalar where you use all execute commands, after you have opened the connection and made a query.

Comment: I couldn't build it :(

Comment: @Dodi replace `Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows.Count;` with `Db.RunQuery(sql).Rows[0].Field<int>(0);`

Comment: It worked Perfectly. Thanks. But Whenever I delete a row from the table, how do I refresh the label ? Lets say I have three rows and I want to delete one, and If I delete a row, the label will keep it to 3 until I do refresh to the pagr! Is there any way I can make the label refresh itself whenever rows are deleted?